# How to summarize values using AngularJS and table HTML?

Tags: angularjs

This is the scenario:

1. One table with 5 rows.
2. Row 1 - displays total purchase.
3. Row 2 - displays total Fruits purchase.
4. Row 3 - displays total Vegetables purchase.
5. Row 4 - Is a fruits table with n fruits, generated dynamically with php.
6. Row 5 - Is a vegetable table with n vegetable, generated dynamically with php.

As you can see in the fiddle link, the user must choose the quantity of a specific product, so the final price for this product is updated and the total and group price as well.

I could do this using jquery, but I would like to accomplish this task using AngularJs.

I've started to code. But so far I have one issue. It dipslays  `$NaN` in the total product line.

1. So, how to avoid display this `$NaN` when there is nothing inside quantity?
2. How to link the 3 totals fields to each individual products group?

Note. The approach I have used is not the best one. Feel free to change the approach.
Any suggestion? [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e9gdpr5x/1/)

```
<table style='width:100% ;border: 2px solid #00BABF;' ng-app=''> 
  <tr>
    <td>Total: $<span id='total'></span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Fruit: $<span id='tot_fruit'></span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Veget: $<span id='tot_veget'></span></td>
  </tr>


  <tr id='fruits'>
     <td>
         <table id='tbl_fruits' style='width:100% ;border: 2px solid red;'>
            <tr>
             <th style=' padding: 10px;  text-align: left;'>Name</th>
             <th style=' padding: 10px;  text-align: left;'>Quanty</th>
             <th style=' padding: 10px;  text-align: left;'>Price</th>
             <th style=' padding: 10px;  text-align: left;'>Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id='Fruit_1ID'>
              <td class="name">Fruit_1</td>
              <td><input id='qty_Fruit_1ID' ng-model='Fruit_1ID'></td>
              <td>$<span id='price_Fruit_1ID'>10</span></td>
              <td>$<span id='tot_Fruit_1ID'>{{Fruit_1ID*10}}</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='Fruit_nID'>
              <td class="name">Fruit_n</td>
              <td><input id='qty_Fruit_nID' ng-model='Fruit_nID'></td>
              <td>$<span id='price_Fruit_nID'>5</span></td>
              <td>$<span id='tot_Fruit_nID'>{{Fruit_nID*5}}</span></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id='vegetable'>
     <td>
         <table id='tbl_vegetabl' style='width:100% ;border: 2px solid green;'>
            <tr>
             <th style=' padding: 10px;  text-align: left;'>Name</th>
             <th style=' padding: 10px;  text-align: left;'>Quanty</th>
             <th style=' padding: 10px;  text-align: left;'>Price</th>
             <th style=' padding: 10px;  text-align: left;'>Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id='Vegetab_1ID'>
              <td class="name">Vegetab_1</td>
              <td><input id='qty_Vegetab_1ID' ng-model='Vegetab_1ID'></td>
              <td>$<span id='price_Vegetab_1ID'>7</span></td>
              <td>$<span id='tot_Vegetab_1ID'>{{Vegetab_1ID*7}}</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='Vegetab_nID'>
              <td class="name">Vegetab_n</td>
              <td><input id='qty_Vegetab_nID' ng-model='Vegetab_nID'></td>
              <td>$<span id='price_Vegetab_nID'>3</span></td>
              <td>$<span id='tot_Vegetab_nID'>{{Vegetab_nID*3}}</span></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, how to avoid display this $NaN when there is nothing inside quantity?
>   How to link the 3 totals fields to each individual products group?

- You could simply use double vertical slash `||` to avoid situation
  when your expression evaluates as `NaN`.
- The same as above.
  But you definitely should use controller and move all logic there, or even to the services.
  [Link to JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiyanov/y5wnzffr/1/)
  I think a good solution is to store price for each food into the variable or even as a constant.

Comment: Hi Aleksey, that is nice. Issue 1 is solved. But the issue 2. In this example I have only 2 fruits. The database could have 2, 20 or 200 fruits. So in this case we should use ` total : {{(Fruit_1ID*10 || 0) + (Fruit_nID*5 || 0) + ...+200 times?  }}` . Yes it works, since I am creating the page dynamically. Do you think is there a better solution for this?. Think about the Grand total field. We should summarize all fruits  and all vegeteables.

Comment: When you get the data from database you could use something like `ng-repeat="fruit in fruites"` for displaying your rows. Than you'll be able to iterate you array and find total price (`calculate()`). And for displaying total price in real-time you could use `$watchCollection` listener and invoke your `calculate()` function